# Rails 5 Turbolinks and Bootstrap button dropdown issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

I'm working on a project that has turbolinks implemented. However, on my machine I don't get the dropdowns to open and certain buttons to work. 
This is my application.js.coffee:

```
# //= require jquery
# //= require jquery.turbolinks
# //= require jquery_ujs
# //= require bootstrap
# //= require turbolinks
# //= require jquery.plugin
# //= require jquery.countdown
# //= require jquery-ui
# //= require tinymce
# //= require tinymce-init
# //= require isotope.pkgd.min
# //= require imagesloaded.pkgd.min
# //= require select2
# //= require select2-full
# //= require manage
# //= require products
# //= require flashcards
# //= require media
# //= require htmls
# //= require quizzes
# //= require product_assets
# //= require content_assets
# //= require cocoon
# //= require bugherd
# //= require bootstrap-sprockets
# //= require_tree .
```

But my bootstrap buttons dropdown won't work plus the whole layout of the page was messed up. Following up on another thread I removed the require of bootstrap and left bootstrap-sprockets in there. That fixed the dropdown issue but my layout is still messed up. If I remove the turbolinks require, the layout goes back to normal. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Check the browser console for javascript errors.

Comment: what does 'layout messed up' mean?  should provide console output/page images/code samples

Comment: What version of `turbolinks` and `rails` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a problem related to [a issue on turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/213) tha has already been resolved, as it is not a real issue but just the case that you manage your scripts accordingly to [Turbolinks documentation](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#observing-navigation-events). You may put your bootstrap script in the `<head>` or make a change into your scripts that initialize bootstrap

**Use**

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", 
    ...
```

**Instead of**

```
document.addEventListener("ready", 
    ...
```